# How to tell to TextMate ignore my Katz's Bundler folder in "Go to File"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, textmate, bundler

I use Katz's Bundler to manage gem dependencies.

Who know, how to tell to TextMate ignore my "vendor/bundler_gems" folder in "Go to File"?

[Image demonstrate my little problem](http://grab.by/238s).

You can see, what I want to find my application.sass, instead "Go to File" find lots of trash from bundler folder.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I find solution:

In dialog "Preferences → Advanced → Folder References", "Folder Pattern" input:

Original pattern:

```
!.*/(\.[^/]*|CVS|_darcs|_MTN|\{arch\}|blib|.*~\.nib|.*\.(framework|app|pbproj|pbxproj|xcode(proj)?|bundle))$
```

I change it to:

```
!.*/(\.[^/]*|CVS|_darcs|_MTN|\{arch\}|blib|.*~\.nib|.*\.(framework|app|pbproj|pbxproj|xcode(proj)?|bundle)|vendor)$
```

...to ignore vendor folder.

Or:

```
!.*/(\.[^/]*|CVS|_darcs|_MTN|\{arch\}|blib|.*~\.nib|.*\.(framework|app|pbproj|pbxproj|xcode(proj)?|bundle)|vendor/bundler_gems)$
```

...to ignore vendor/bundler_gems only.

Comment: You can do this at the Project level too

Comment: Note you will need to recreate your folder reference after changing the pattern.

Answer (score 3):

TextMate keeps folder references setting per project basis in .tmproj file.

Changing the regular expression in TextMate preferences dialog doesn't update project file. This means that first answer to this question didn't solve similar problem I had. Outside plugins might have something to do with it (Project+ for example).

In first answer doesn't work:

Open up your project file with other editor than TextMate and edit the "regexFolderFilter" key by hand.

*Sidenote: Normally forward slashes should be escaped. Don't know how TextMate actually runs the regular expression since outcome is the same with or without escaping.*

Comment: No need to open it with another editor - just hold down Option when opening it in TextMate (from the Open Recent... menu, if you like).